# Being laid off and not sure if I'm still entry level or beyond?

Tags: software-industry, job-search

I'm an embedded software engineer and my company is having a RIF which is impacting at least half of the employees in my part of the organization. We are a very well known company and generally well respected. I started after graduation and by the time my release date rolls around I'll have a little over 2 years of working experience.

I have two releases under my belt and working on finishing up a third release this month with hopefully a fourth based on extensive work I did in the 3rd & 4th quarter of last year.

I'm honestly not sure where that puts me in terms of what jobs to look for after my tenure here. **Am I experienced enough to go for a non-entry level, non new grad role?**  I figure that I'm too far away from my graduation date to be a new grad anymore and I've had two raises and bonuses in my time with my company already. I'm fearful that I won't be seen as competitive when going for the regular, non Sr. Software Engineer roles although I know I can accomplish any development task if given the opportunity.

Any advice from experienced folks would be incredibly welcome!

Comment: With two years of experience I would not consider you to be "entry level".

Comment: Hi @Sarah and welcome to the site, it's a bit unclear what it is you are asking, are you essentially asking 'How can I tell if I am still considered entry level?'

Comment: Benny, Thanks for your response, just the information I was looking for. Obviously not unclear to folks able to answer the question. :)

Comment: You are not considered entry level for most companies, however, larger corporations (ie, Microsoft/Apple/IBM etc) might still encourage you to apply via their "new grad" gateways.  I was told by some that 2 years out was still acceptable.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere This is an extremely good point. I can't go into finite details about the work I've done but I was able to take on some lead roles in my time already and many of my colleagues that I work with on a daily basis have 10-20 years of experience just at our company alone and I have certainly held my own on doing the same level as work as they have.

Comment: I honestly came into the role worried I wouldn't measure up or be good enough but I've met and exceeded all tasks. I don't consider myself amazing, however, but coworker & manager response shown that I've well exceeded expectations. On my current project my colleague didn't realize I graduated less than two years ago and thought I had been with the company for quite a while already due to my expertise. another expressed repeatedly extreme dismay and disgust that I'm getting cut, multiple times. He's been very impressed with the work I've done and also didn't realize I'm a recent grad.

Comment: As an aside, this question is improperly marked as closed and unanswerable when it was answered.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your level of experience is typically considered a *"Junior Software Engineer"*.  So that means that you have between 1 to 3 years experience and a firm grasp of the life cycle.  If you look around online you will get a better sense of what is expected from someone with that title.

Hope that helps.